# Use cast features with non-cast devices

Tags: android, chromecast, google-cast

I have a remote playback device that is not a cast-device (let's call him *Johnny 5* for now).

From a client app, I want to be able to cast content to a Chromecast or to my *Johnny 5* device. The app is based on the [Cast SDK v3](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/developers).

In order to integrate my non-cast device, I built a Media Router Provider and extended the [Session](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/cast/framework/Session) & [SessionProvider](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/cast/framework/SessionProvider) classes. The Session Provider is added in the [`getAdditionalSessionProviders`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/cast/framework/OptionsProvider.html#getAdditionalSessionProviders(android.content.Context)) method of my [OptionsProvider](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/cast/framework/OptionsProvider) class.

I managed to make things work: my device appears in the list of the detected devices with the Chromecast (thanks to the MediaRouterProvider), and when I select it, session is started, and then I can cast contents on it.

However, it seems like the [RemoteMediaClient](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/cast/framework/media/RemoteMediaClient) object is Google-cast specific (cannot be used with non-cast devices), like a lot of Cast SDK features (mini controller, expanded controller...).

Question here regards the Cast Dialog, the Remote Control Notification and the Lock Screen: is that possible to use these with my non-cast device ? Or do I have to code the whole bunch to 'mimic' the Cast SDK features ?

Regarding the Cast Dialog, I would like to be able to customize it to have the same behavior as for the Chromecast without coding my own device picker or overriding the default button behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The majority of work would be on your side, coding most everything for non-cast devices. Cast APIs, as you've noticed, do not interact with Sessions that are not CastSessions. So your options is to write an interface that is already implemented by Cast SDK for cast devices and by you for non-cast devices and try to use that common interface as much as possible. Getting things like lock screen amounts to creating a MediaStyle notification; CastSdk handles that for when there is a CastSession involved and you need to create a similar notification when a different type of Session is involved. This is true for almost all UI elements that the Cast SDK provides out of the box.

Comment: since last update on the play services (11.5.09), the "start" method of my Session subclass is not called anymore. I'm stuck on the "Session starting" event. Is that a bug you are aware of?